# login with facebook account

Tags: php, facebook

we have created a website and which consists of registration and login, what i want to do is i want to add the facilities to the users to login with their facebook login, i am using php and smarty framework, i have google it but i cant find it anywhere, i could not understand much more from http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/overview.php....

Example, here in stackoverflow i haven't signup, instead i login with facebook account, i want to do the same for my website

Comment: Please don't use the http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/overview.php pages except for historical purposes. That tutorial uses the old style way of doing things, but Facebook has new techniques now and the tutorial was never updated.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you to integrate facebook connect with the [php SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/). I integrate it successfully on several website without any trouble, the [wiki from the php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/wiki/Home/b5ebc4d53ae7e82848ef6617f1f800282a5968fe) has been a bit messy recently, but you can find information if you search a bit through the github repository.

Comment: here is the link to do that http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=99187